# How to compare a row value to all the rows in a different column and separate all the rows that match using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file, containing info of some banks. There are 9 columns in total. There are two columns, `id` and `parentid`, which contain the id for each bank and also it's `parentid` (`parentid = 0`, if the given bank is parent which is indicated by `'Type = T'`).

I need to separate all the banks into separate data frames such that all the children of a parent record should be in the same dataframe as the parent record.

Sample data:

```
type,symbol,price,quantity,expirydate,strikeprice,amendtime,id,parentid
T,ICICIBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103030,1234,0
T,AXISBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103031,1235,0
T,SBIBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103032,1236,0
P,ICICIBANK,1100,100,20121210,120,20121209103030,1237,1234
P,AXISBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103031,1238,1235
T,ICICIBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103035,1239,0
T,.CITIBANK,1000,101,20121210,120,20121209103036,1240,0
P,ICICIBANK,1100,100,20121210,120,20121209103030,1241,1234
P,ICICIBANK,1100,100,20121210,120,20121209103035,1242,1239
```

I have loaded the csv file using pandas and separated child and parent based on the Type column.

I am stuck with remaining part.[This is what a sample dataframe looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9px7o.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` can help here:

```
df.groupby(np.where(df.parentid==0, df.id, df.parentid))
```

will give you an iterable of tuples (id, dataframe_for_that_id_and_its_childs).

Example:

```
for i, g in df.groupby(np.where(df.parentid==0, df.id, df.parentid)):
    print(i)
    print(g)
```

gives:

```
1234
  type     symbol  price    ...          amendtime    id  parentid
0    T  ICICIBANK   1000    ...     20121209103030  1234         0
3    P  ICICIBANK   1100    ...     20121209103030  1237      1234
7    P  ICICIBANK   1100    ...     20121209103030  1241      1234

[3 rows x 9 columns]
1235
  type    symbol  price    ...          amendtime    id  parentid
1    T  AXISBANK   1000    ...     20121209103031  1235         0
4    P  AXISBANK   1000    ...     20121209103031  1238      1235

[2 rows x 9 columns]
1236
  type   symbol  price    ...          amendtime    id  parentid
2    T  SBIBANK   1000    ...     20121209103032  1236         0

[1 rows x 9 columns]
1239
  type     symbol  price    ...          amendtime    id  parentid
5    T  ICICIBANK   1000    ...     20121209103035  1239         0
8    P  ICICIBANK   1100    ...     20121209103035  1242      1239

[2 rows x 9 columns]
1240
  type     symbol  price    ...          amendtime    id  parentid
6    T  .CITIBANK   1000    ...     20121209103036  1240         0

[1 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks Serge!! Worked like a charm. I was not able to vote you as I am a new user..

Answer (score 0):

This will split the dataframe into a dictionary of dataframes (the keys are the parent id):

```
selection = df['parentid'].mask(df['parentid']==0, df['id'])
{sel: df.loc[selection == sel] for sel in selection.unique()}
```